# PHP Fetchall only returning column header

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database that I am trying to query to get information to display to my user. I have used

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

before when retrieving a single row or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

with good results.  However, it is my understanding that it is better practice to use PDO so that is what I am trying to do.

The problem I am running into is that my results are only showing me the first row of the data I need. In this instance it is displaying the column header over and over and never giving me the data.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ? FROM application");
$stmt->bindparam(1, $application_ID);

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['application_ID'];
}
```

Here are the results

```
     application_IDapplication_IDapplication_IDapplication_ID
```

Comment: By the way. I have spent about 2 hours looking for a solution to this issue. So, if this is something that is out there already or is super easy then I apologize. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good that you are aware that MySQL has been oficially deprecated and now we are supposed to used MySQLi or better yet, PDO.

Since you are not accepting any user input, there is no need of using a prepared statement.

Simply do this:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM application");

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row){
   echo $row['application_ID'];
  //output other rows here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense what you are saying about not having to use prepared statement in this instance. Can you tell me how I would be able to make this work if I were? I have a feeling that I am would need an output param in my binding. Is that right?

Comment: You are welcome. If you were to pass a param, you'd do something like this `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM application WHERE id = :id ");` then pass the parameter as `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);` and then execute it `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the php documentation [pdo::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

you have to use `fetchAll`, instead of `fetchall`.